# Selecting every 3rd row in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to select every third blank row in excel. Once I do that, I need to enter a formula into this third blank row that extracts the contents of a cell below. I would like to have it so this will be done for every third blank. A macro would be fine, I am just not familiar with VBA code so I am not sure where to start.

[image: Here is an example]

You'll notice that every third blank row contains the ID from column a in the row below it, and the name from column g below the third blank. Any ideas of how this can be done efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a column which repeats every 3 rows and filter on that!

You may also be looking for [Pivot Tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

Answer (score 0):

Add two columns before column "A", so that your id column becomes column "C".

1. Now fill all cells with value 1 till the last of your data range in column "A".
2. In cell "B1" use below formula & fill down till your data

   =ISNUMBER(D1)

Now add filter ( Ctrl + Shift + L ). And filter data in column "B" with "FALSE"

If you can follow these steps exactly, you will get all rows you want.

Then use this formula in Than apply filter.